# How can I show this Scss/Sass Value?

Tags: css, sass

I want some help with the following Scss code. I'm trying to build a color palet from 50 to 900 and want to show the color value.

```
$colors: (
      "gray": (
        "gray-50": (
          "color": #FFF3E0
        )
      )
    ) !default;
    
    @each $colorname, $color in $colors {
      .#{$colorname} {
        color: map-get(map-get($colors, gray));
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do or what the problem is?

Comment: What increment value are you wanting? 1? 50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might fit your needs.

```
$colors: (
  "gray": (
    "50": #FFF3E0,
  ),
) !default;

@each $color-name, $shades in $colors {
  @each $shade, $color in $shades {
    .#{$color-name}-#{$shade} {
      color: #{$color};  
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
.gray-50 {
  color: #FFF3E0;
}
```